# Component did update prevState not working

Tags: reactjs, components

How to update component when states getusersmsgcount changes. The problem is, without manually reloading page state does not change. And this.state and prevState is same. Following is my code. Please Help. If I call this.updateCount() in componentdidUpdate() without prevstate it gets into infinite loop

```
    this.state = {
    getusersmsgcount: 0,
};

componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCount();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const prevuseritem = prevState.getusersmsgcount;
        const currentuseritem = this.state.getusersmsgcount;
        console.log("Previous user item = ", prevuseritem, "Current user item = ", currentuseritem)
        if(prevuseritem !== currentuseritem) {
            this.updateCount();
        }
    }
    
    updateCount = () => {
        CometChat.getUnreadMessageCount().then((counter) => {
            const summsgs = Object.values(counter.users);
            const usersmsgcount = summsgs.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
            return this.setState((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState, 
                getusersmsgcount: usersmsgcount,
            }));
        })
    }
```

Comment: The component automatically updates when the state changes. Are you saying the component is not updating on this.setState call in updateCount function? Why are you returning this.setState from the updateCount function? Can you try removing "return"?

Comment: @Ammar  Are you saying the component is not updating on this.setState call in updateCount function? Yes

Why are you returning this.setState from the updateCount function? Can you try removing "return"? In both cases getusersmsgcount does not update without page reload